# Convert a byte[] to its string representation in binary

Tags: c#

I need to convert a `Byte[]` to a `string` which contain a binary number sequence. I cannot use `Encoding` because it just encodes bytes into characters!

For example, having this array:

```
new byte[] { 254, 1 };
```

I want this output:

```
"1111111000000001"
```

Comment: Are you saying you want a string that's for example "0110010010100100"?

Comment: yep ! thats exactly i need i already have it on a `byte[]`

Comment: you need the bytes converted to string "as is"?

Comment: What encoding are you talking about? I mean, what is your idea about encoding that you don't want it?

Comment: Could you provide us with a sample Byte[] input

Comment: Gabriel -- Yes thats what i need !

Comment: My `byte[]` array contains a data from a `memoryStream`

Comment: @Sudantha give us the input and the value of the byte[] as an example.

Comment: `var stream = new MemoryStream();` `byte[] x =stream.ToArray();`     <--------- Its from a memory stream

Comment: I updated the question and added an example; please correct it if it's not what you need.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

You can convert any numeric integer primitive to its binary representation as a string with `Convert.ToString`. Doing this for each `byte` in your array and concatenating the results is very easy with LINQ:

```
var input = new byte[] { 254 }; // put as many bytes as you want in here
var result = string.Concat(input.Select(b => Convert.ToString(b, 2)));
```

**Update:**

The code above will not produce a result having exactly 8 characters per input byte, and this will make it impossible to know what the input was just by looking at the result. To get exactly 8 chars per byte, a small change is needed:

```
var result = string.Concat(input.Select(b => Convert.ToString(b, 2).PadLeft(8, '0')));
```

Comment: Hi john i think this works for me.. i was able to  count the length of the result... but when i try to take it to a `textbox` form docent load ... any idea ? :)

Comment: Thanks John ... i was able to take it to `richTextBox` .. THanks a lot for ur help and support

Answer (score 3):

```
string StringIWant = BitConverter.ToString(byteData);
```

But i suggest work with `Encoding`..

```
string System.Text.Encoding.UTF8.GetString(byte[])
```

**EDIT**: For like `10101011010`

From @Quintin Robinson's answer;

```
StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
foreach (byte b in myByteArray)
    sb.Append(b.ToString("X2"));

string hexString = sb.ToString();
```

Comment: kind of comes a s `FF-FF-` ..... i think thats `hexa` .. do you know now to convert into binary `10101010`

Answer (score 2):

Perhaps you can use the [BitArray](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.collections.bitarray.aspx) class to accomplish what you are looking for?  They have some sample code in the reference which should be pretty easy to convert to what you are looking for.

Answer (score 1):

Will [BitConverter.ToString](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/3a733s97.aspx) work for you?

Answer (score 1):

```
byte[] bList = { 0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5 };
string s1 = BitConverter.ToString(bList);
string s2 = "";
foreach (byte b in bList)
{
     s2 += b.ToString();
}
```

in this case s1 ="01-02-03-04-05"
and s2= "012345"
I don't really get what are you trying to achieve.

Comment: Personally I've understood what he wants to achieve. What I really don't understand is what are you trying to achieve in this example?